# adapter dual switch

Tags: electrical

The switch in this adaptor only disconnects one of the live lines. What kind of switch where both are disconnected when you turn it off?

[image]

What is the advantage of the latter (or hazard of the former)?

top and bottom view of it. It's 240 volts. 2 live hots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yup, no UL listing or other testing lab medallion.  Yeah, this is an "everything socket" adapter to NEMA 1, intended for the North American market for appliances which don't mind 120V/60Hz. The design is completely incompetent, and is surely from our "definitely not currency manipulators" friends from the north, the ones with the wall.

Answer (score 2):

### Philippines:

You're sunk.  You can't do that with this adapter.  It's not a Philippines adapter, it's a North America/Japan adapter.

*(For our readers, the former USA-developed areas of the Philippines use USA-style split-phase, but for nationalism reasons serve only 240V so neutral does not exist. This makes it compatible with the rest of the country which uses standard Euro 1-of-3-phases of 230V. In USA areas, since both wires are far from ground potential, both must be switched for safety.)*

This problem is greatly compounded by the unfortunate policy in the Philippines of using the NEMA 1 and NEMA 5 receptacles for 240V (when there's a perfectly good spec called NEMA 6 specifically for what they are doing, but good luck telling a whole country they're using the wrong socket).  So you have polarized NEMA 5 receptacles with the neutral being 120V from earth and the hot being the opposite 120V from earth.

Honestly, you will never find a BS1363 that switches both legs. That is simply not required for that appication (anywhere else but Philippines).  I would advise actually installing a *proper* BS1363 right next to a 2-pole switch, and then superglue and sticker over the on-socket switch, so people use the off-socket switch.

Although honestly, Britain are the only people in the world who put switches on receptacles.

### Everywhere else in North America, Colombia and Japan:

Under the UK BS1363 standard, the switch on the socket is required to switch off the **hot** wire.  The neutral wire is (supposed to be) near earth potential, so there's not a lot of hazard to leaving it connected.  **So there is no need to switch neutral**.

Hence one which switches both is unlikely to exist.

North America's voltage is lower, but has the same "hot + neutral + earth" scheme, with neutral also (supposed to be) near earth potential.

It needs to be polarized so the switch is switching the 120V hot wire.   On the NEMA 1 and NEMA 5 15A connectors, polarization is done one of two ways:

- The ground pin assures correct orientation of the socket.
- The neutral slot on a socket is taller than the hot slot, so 2-prong plugs simply have a taller neutral pin.

On 3-prong plugs, they don't bother with the tall neutral.

This thing appears to be 2-prong and with no polarization.  It's an incompetently designed Cheese cheapie, and the switch is theater (because 50% of the time it'll be switching the neutral). No testing lab stamp, of course.

Comment: Harper. I live in the Philppines, the two plug is the two hot wire in the US, or 240 volts (with no grounding as we don't use it as you know). I used a tester. The switch disconnects only one of the hot sides. I want an adaptor where the switch disconnects both hots.

Comment: @jtl ohhhhh.... Snap.... That changes everything.  I'm sorry, I should've recognized you.

Comment: please see edited top and bottom pic of it.

Comment: Harper, if would be used on motor or AC appliances. I know it would be hazardous. But it's only connected to this switching adapter see   https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img921/5835/odJeWl.jpg    My question is, if one of the line is still hot.. would it somehow affect the equipment which needs 5V DC, it's very expensive equipment hence concerned of the adapter where only one side is switched off.

Comment: @jtl the deciding factor there will be grounding, unless the item is super cheap. Meanwell is pretty good stuff, note the genuine testing lab medallions.  *Oh snap, the adapter does not pass through ground*.  Any other way you can ground it?

Comment: this is picture of the back of the meanwell adaptor https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/9499/pOiKLr.jpg  It has no grounding. It and equipment comes from Russia. The meanwell is just connected to the 5V equipment, how can the white Adaptor (connected to the meanwell) with one side switched off affect the equipment or cause any hazard?

Comment: @Jtl Ah, there it is, in your earlier picture.  The square within a square indicates "double insulated".  And someone (ETL?) has put it to the test  Should be alright.

Comment: So no problem connecting the Meanwell to the white adaptor with one side turned off by switch only, and other line live. The equipment is a DPSS (Diode Pumped Solid State) laser. I don't want to the laser activating suddenly.

Comment: However, in the entire house, the same white adaptor many of them with one side switchable only powers rice cookers, electrical fan, and many appliances. It's used as switch. Thank God the entire house is protected by full house GFCI. Or could it be hazard. For others without full house GFCI. Then it may be a hazard, isn't it.

Comment: @Jtl yes, it'd be a big hazard.  As far as using the switch on a no-brand drugstore cheapie everything adapter in a life-safety application, *do you even need to ask?*

Comment: Look at this picture https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/9067/2LYetp.jpg I was able to connect 2 pole with 2 switches. Imagine each pole is connected to one of the switches. So if I need to open it. I need to open both switches? What do you think of it? Why didn't you suggest it to me a month ago?